# SQL back up issues

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have been doing some research on best backup procedures for largish (27.678gb) MYSQL database tables.

Currently we are using a program called Rapidsync (which is a offsite backup tool) but it is slow and it locks the tables it's currently backing up therefore causing downtime/slowness of sql.

Our current server is running Windows 2008 r2 with SQL server 2008 (on the same box) also.

Hardware specs for the dedicated server are:

16gb Ram 
CPU intel xeon E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz 
1 TB hard drive

In terms of databases we have 58 in total varying in size in which some need to backed up weekly ideally or even daily.

Through a program we use called Navicat you can tunnel to a database using SSH and copy databases manually, is this a reliable and feasible option if we were to install it on our local machine and copy them across? Or would it be more secure/efficient to use SQL Dump maybe?

I hope I have given all of the necessary info but please do ask if you need to know more.

P.S Only free options at this moment as we are on a tight budget! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned SSH, so I suppose the backups can be done also on other server than the database server itself. For Unix, you can use great tool [Percona xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/index.html), which is free and supports online (without locking) backup of InnoDB database files and also incremental backups. Maybe it is possible to compile it also on Windows (part of it is written in C, part in Perl).

So you can setup weekly full backup and daily incremental backups. The tool will keep track of which pages of the InnoDB datafile has been changed and will copy only those.